# Live server error : InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [welcome] not found

Tags: php, deployment, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3

I have developed a Laravel (**Version 5.3**) application which works well on the local machine with XAMPP.

On making it live on **Hostinger.in**, it gives error like

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: 

View [welcome] not found in FileViewFinder

at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('welcome', array('C:\xampp-old\htdocs\bluesky_db\laravel\resources\views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79
```

It still takes path of Xampp/htdocc/xxx. Also, this is my first project deployment on the server with Laravel, so I am not able to correctly configure my `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `php artisan config:cache` or `php artisan config:clear` on your SSH